# Chinese characters instead of non-latin characters (Mojibake bug?!)

Tags: ios, react-native, mojibake

Using `react-native` `v0.31.0` on `iOS` (currently on `iOS9` and `iOS10`).

I have a non-latin text inside a `<Text>` `Component` and sometimes I see it like this:
[image]

But it actually should look like this:
[image]

My walk-around is:

- Sniffed the network, and the data looks as it should
- `iOS` native side and the data to draw is already broken

I saw these related issues:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7646
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8914
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9104

And this PR:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9313

But none of these solved the issue for me.

This behaviour only happens intermittently, but on a slow connection it happens consistently.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worth noting, the data from the server is sent using chunked transfer encoding and gzip compressed.

Comment: What is the server? Looks like "Content-Type: text/*; Charset= " charset has been lost. Chunked encoding can be buggy...

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in React Native v0.38: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10110